# Error of Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo , while doing SpringJDBC example

Tags: spring, maven, spring-jdbc

I am doing Springjdbc example from the site 
http://www.journaldev.com/2593/spring-jdbc-and-jdbctemplate-crud-with-datasource-example-tutorial.
After ececuting i am getting error of

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ SpringJDBCExample ---
Feb 16, 2015 10:43:41 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5d099f62: startup date [Mon Feb 16 10:43:41 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 16, 2015 10:43:41 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.main.SpringMain.main(SpringMain.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 13 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.407s
Finished at: Mon Feb 16 10:43:42 IST 2015
Final Memory: 5M/75M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project SpringJDBCExample: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

MY POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringJDBCExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

   <dependency> 
  <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId> 
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId> 
  <version>2.0.0</version> 
</dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring JDBC Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

PLEASE HEPL ME AS I AM NEW TO THIS FRAMEWORK

Comment: ```java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist```. Do you have ```spring.xml``` in your classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First stop server,
clean project,
if you are using netbeans, clean and build it.
Then delete users/XXX/.m2 folder,
then again build maven. 
Hope fully your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `spring-config.xml` file to the `resources` folder and check for proper XML definitions, To enable debugging and stack trace error in maven use,

```
clean install -X -e
```

in the maven goal and execute.

Better try cleaning `.m2` and do a maven `install`, then from your `IDE` , `clean and build` project. Check `build path` for further understanding.